# How can I terminate data input by enter?

Tags: c++

How can I terminate input numbers by press 'enter' using 'istream_iterator'? In my program, only if I press other key than 'enter' input is finished.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<int> vec = { istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>() };
copy(begin(vec), end(vec), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You can't, it reads until it fails (that is, you enter a non-integer) or the stream ends. In your terminal, Ctrl-Z may terminate the stream. See your documentation for details.

Comment: [Ctrl]+Z will terminate the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own stream buffer. Just an example (not verified):

```
class nl_to_eof_buf : public std::streambuf
{

  std::streambuf* src;
  char ch;

  traits_type::int_type underflow() override
  {
    ch = src->sbumpc();
    if ( ch == '\n' )
      return traits_type::eof();
    setg( &ch, &ch, &ch+1 );
    return ch;
  }

public:

  nl_to_eof_buf( std::streambuf* buf ) : src( buf ) { setg( &ch, &ch+1, &ch+1 ); }

};

int main()
{
  //
  std::streambuf* orig = cin.rdbuf();
  nl_to_eof_buf buf( orig );

  //
  cin.rdbuf( &buf );
  vector<int> vec ={ istream_iterator<int>( cin ), istream_iterator<int>() };
  cin.rdbuf( orig );

  //
  copy( begin( vec ), end( vec ), ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " " ) );

  return 0;
}
```